# What permissions should be assigned for the "git" user in gitolite

Tags: gitolite

I set up git and gitolite with some help from members on this forum and using these instructions:

https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite

In the instructions one of the requirements is:

> a dedicated `userid` to host the repos (in this document, we assume it is '`git`'), with shell access ONLY by '`su - git`' from some other `userid` on the same server.

Are these the correct permissions shown below?

```
sudo chown git /home/git
sudo chmod -R 755 /home/git
```

...or are there more appropriate settings to provide necessary security and functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no:

For `/home/git`, `700` would work too if you want something "more secure".

But you don't have to protect everything the same way within the `git` homedir, especially the `.ssh` directory.

The main point is to avoid '`+gw`' and '`+ow`' on `/home/git` itself: if '`group`' or '`others`' are writable, ssh won't work (the ssh daemon will refuse to consider `/home/git/.ssh` content)

See "[Creating SSH keys for Gerrit and Hudson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3712443/creating-ssh-keys-for-gerrit-and-hudson/3712619#3712619)" as an example of appropriate ssh protections.

Answer (score 1):

I created the Gitolite hosting user as below on Fedora. Other distributions have similar options in the adduser command

```
useradd \
--comment ‘git hosting user’ \
--user-group \
--system \
--shell /bin/bash \
--create-home \
--home-dir /home/git git
```

On Fedora, this command creates a system account git with local password locked. The default option for the useradd command when --password option isn’t supplied is to disable the password.

As I understand, this would give the hosting user an interactive non-login shell like so:

```
sudo su - git
```

NB: This question was put out a while ago, but I had the same question when I went about installing Gitolite (and didn't find an answer). I figured it out (or so, I think). So here it is.