# Why my SSH hang on there while connecting to github?

Tags: ssh, github, cygwin

This is what I tried to do ten times today without success:

- make a key with ssh-keygen.
- open ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub with Gedit or Notepad++ and copy the contents.
- Go to account settings on github.com
- Go to SSH Keys
- Click on the Add Key button.
- give the key a title
- paste the key into the key box.
- Save the key (enter my github password to verify).

Then, I run '$ ssh -vT git@github.com' in cygwin, but it always hang on there. Here is the output:

```
$ ssh -vT git@github.com
OpenSSH_6.0p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1c 10 May 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/eason.wu/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/eason.wu/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for github.com
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to github.com [207.97.227.239] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/eason.wu/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/eason.wu/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
```

Does any one meet this problem, any solution will be appreciated

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make sure you did copy the public key as *one* line, because a copy from an editor can sometime buffer the content of that key as several lines.

If you still have an issue, check other SSH debug tips at "[Unable to Git-push master to Github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922210/unable-to-git-push-master-to-github/922461#922461)".
A `ssh -vvvT git@github.com` can display more debug information.

---

The [OP Eason Wu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/701457/eason-wu) comments:

> I found the real reason of this problem, it is caused by my network.
> **Some websites are prohibited by my company**, I would think it also affects GitHub service.
> After I turn on an VPN connection, and retest again with `ssh -vvvT git@github.com`, it passed successfully

Comment: Yeah, I did copy it in one line. I also created a config file like the tip mentioned, it still doesn't work. And after use option `-vvvT`, it throw a new message out, `Could not load "/home/eason.wu/.ssh/id_rsa" as a RSA1 public key`, not sure if my key is not correct? But I generate the key following https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys. It's very strange. Anyway, thanks for your reply.

Comment: @EasonWu check you `.ssh` protection: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3712443/creating-ssh-keys-for-gerrit-and-hudson/3712619#3712619

Comment: I added full control over the log on user for the file under .ssh, still cannot connect to server. I download the tool provided by github, it works well via SSH way,　there should be some steps I did wrong. Thanks for your suggestion!!!

Comment: I found the real reason of this problem, it is caused by my network. Some website are prohibited by my company, I would think it also affects github service. After I turn on an VPN connection, and retest again with `ssh -vvvT git@github.com`, it passed successfully.

Comment: @EasonWu Excellent. I have included your conclusion in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: I had the same problem, but after testing with this ssh command, it asked me to recognize the host key, and this solved the question here.

Comment: @ThiagoChaves Did you mean it ask you about `known_hosts`?

Comment: @VonC yes, that's right.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone coming here recently looking for a solution, this was happening to me too, however in the debug (as per above instruction) the connection to GitHub never established.

My output looked like:

```
OpenSSH_7.9p1 Ubuntu-10, OpenSSL 1.1.1b  26 Feb 2019
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/preston/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "github.com" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to github.com [2607:7700:0:1a:0:1:c01e:ff70] port 22.
```

I noticed the IPv6 address in the last line and thought that might be the issue. So I sourced an article on changing it to use an IPv4 address in the global ssh settings.

Changing to IPv4 worked.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35113901/3818056

Answer (score 0):

For me, the issue was the router I was connected to was using WPA, not WPA2/3.  Once I changed to a network that didn't have this issue my repo was instantly cloned with ssh.

Answer (score -2):

I solved this by adding GitHub "github.com" in the whitelist of my router. You can also overcome this by VPN however it will require another set of steps to find a VPN and setup.