# Configure git to use IPv4 instead of IPv6 by default

Tags: git, ipv6, ipv4

Checking the environment variables and also HTTP configuration options does not reveal something. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

With git 2.8 (March 2016), you can force `git fetch`/`push`/`clone` to use IPV4 or IPV6.
(for `git pull`, see below Git 2.16, Q1 2018)

See [commit c915f11](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c915f11eb4922e154e29cf62d3b549d65c06a170) (03 Feb 2016) by [Eric Wong (`ele828`)](https://github.com/ele828).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit e84d5e9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e84d5e9fa178a027b1c8b9f6e22c9173dcda03b3), 24 Feb 2016)</sup>

> ### `connect` & `http`: support `-4` and `-6` switches for remote operations
>
> Sometimes it is necessary to force IPv4-only or IPv6-only operation on networks where name lookups may return a non-routable address and stall remote operations.
>
> ```
> -4, --ipv4:
> ```
>
> Use IPv4 addresses only, ignoring IPv6 addresses.
>
> ```
> -6; --ipv6:
> ```
>
> Use IPv6 addresses only, ignoring IPv4 addresses.

---

Update Git 2.16 (Q1 2018): Contrary to the documentation, "`git pull -4/-6 other-args`" did not ask the underlying "`git fetch`" to go over IPv4/IPv6, which has been corrected.

See [commit ffb4568](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ffb4568afed7c3eaa20b000683bb82a761d8f717) (19 Nov 2017) by [Shuyu Wei (``)](https://github.com/).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit c2b6135](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c2b6135a1b52a567c92286bb1d3345b6cb0db584), 27 Nov 2017)</sup>

---

With Git 2.29 (Q4 2020), "[`git fetch --all --ipv4/--ipv6`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/6854689e65700b361eb5d7ff3d4af01bd3e650fe/Documentation/git-fetch.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch))</sup>" forgot to pass the protocol options to instances of the "git fetch" that talk to individual remotes, which has been corrected.

See [commit 4e735c1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4e735c13267e65f8c37fc3e7dfaacb36e5d51ab8) (15 Sep 2020) by [Alex Riesen (`ar-cetitec`)](https://github.com/ar-cetitec).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 6854689](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6854689e65700b361eb5d7ff3d4af01bd3e650fe), 22 Sep 2020)</sup>

> ### [`fetch`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4e735c13267e65f8c37fc3e7dfaacb36e5d51ab8): pass `--ipv4` and `--ipv6` options to sub-fetches
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Alex Riesen</sup>

> The options indicate user intent for the whole fetch operation, and ignoring them in sub-fetches (i.e. "`--all`" and recursive fetching of submodules) is quite unexpected when, for instance, it is intended to limit all of the communication to a specific transport protocol for some reason.

---

With Git 2.42 (Q3 2023), the invalid options `--no-ipv4` ou `--no-ipv6` are rejected early.

See [commit a2dad48](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a2dad4868bf0681f63fe10264c171b5a547324a5), [commit ae2c912](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ae2c912c04cf9902653409d686ca6d5017c3906f) (18 Jul 2023) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 9562f19](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9562f19026f1dcdfcfda86c2c9b7cff21c8b0642), 27 Jul 2023)</sup>

> ### [`fetch`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a2dad4868bf0681f63fe10264c171b5a547324a5): reject `--no-ipv[46]`

> Now we have introduced `OPT_IPVERSION()`, tweak its implementation so that "[`git clone`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/a2dad4868bf0681f63fe10264c171b5a547324a5/Documentation/git-clone.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone))</sup>, "[`git fetch`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/a2dad4868bf0681f63fe10264c171b5a547324a5/Documentation/git-fetch.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch))</sup>, and "[`git push`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/a2dad4868bf0681f63fe10264c171b5a547324a5/Documentation/git-push.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push))</sup> reject the negated form of Use only IP version N options.

You will therefore see "unknown option" if you are using `--no-ipv[46]`.

Comment: @nobeh Yes, I just compiled and tested git 2.8-rc0 in my ubuntu. That seems to work just fine.

Comment: @nobeh I believe this answer is better than my (currently accepted) answer. Consider marking this one as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 87):

The more generic solution (that also works for BSD) is to edit the global  `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` or per-user `~/.ssh/config` and add/replace the entry:

```
AddressFamily any
```

with the following line (where `inet` corresponds to `ipv4`):

```
AddressFamily inet
```

You can also set this for just a single host:

```
Host example.com
    AddressFamily inet
```

Comment: Explanation: `inet` means ipv4 and `inet6` means ipv6.

Comment: This is only applicable if the remote host uses SSH. Given the OP mentioned checking HTTP options, it sounds like this specific case uses HTTP.

Comment: This solution is perfect for bitbucket as their IPv6 solution is much much slower than their IPv4 when using git.

Comment: +1 thank you - this helped me: When I use Speedify VPN and want to push to a gitlab repo, I would usually get a long delay (almost feels like a hang/freeze) before the git push works. But I put your setting `AddressFamily inet` in the config file entry for gitlab and this now means git pushes happen quickly, near instantly and probably the same as when not running the Speedify VPN. Thank you!

Comment: Note that on Windows, the config file is located here: C:\Program Files\Git\etc\ssh\ssh_config. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26266778/ssh-config-file-for-windows-git

Answer (score 14):

In 99% of cases, you should *not* be doing this. The real answer to the question is **fix your IPv6 connection**.

Failing that, you can edit `/etc/gai.conf` to prefer IPv4 over IPv6. gai.conf modifies the behaviour of `getaddrinfo()`, which almost all IPv6–supporting applications use to resolve hostnames.

Almost all systems ship with a copy of /etc/gai.conf within their `glibc` or `libc` package. If it is missing from /etc, usually I find a template copy is lurking somewhere within /usr/share/doc, for you to copy into /etc and modify accordingly.

Comment: It's not MY connection that needs fixing, but the WIFI-du-jour that I happen to sit on...

Comment: Was not aware of this file. Good redirection away from solving an issue at the wrong place.

Comment: This seems to be a good solution, as it just changes order of preference, just uncomment the 4th line in comment as mentioned in gist ( Note: Not my gist ) 
https://gist.github.com/hackjutsu/d189a0cc489d54e3920041e1231fb179

Comment: "The real answer to the question is fix your IPv6 connection.". This sounds like great advice, thanks. I indeed prefer to understand this and fix it b/f having to resort to workarounds. However, can you give some pointers as to what may be wrong with the connection? I mean, is it a WiFi, router or nm Network adapter setting?

Comment: @Kiteloopdesign There are so many variables at play I literally can’t give specific advice. Everything you’ll need to check literally falls under general network troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1):

There are situations where upgrade git or where IPV6 is running but not working as expected, for example, under Windows Linux subsystem, my solutions is simple: just add the git/httpb/ssh IPV4 location on /etc/hosts.

Use `host` to get the IPV4 address and append it to /etc/hosts with name for your own use, for example, `1.1.1.1 git4.server.com`

Answer (score 0):

For those that are using Ubuntu/Debian, the best way to have the latest git version is following the steps below, taken from [here](https://tecadmin.net/install-git-on-ubuntu/).

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa  
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install git
```

Updating for a version 2.19+ plus the solution above, proposed by Anthony C Howe has solved my problem.