# Jenkins pipeline git command submodule update

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I want to update submodule on git clone.

Is there a way to do this with Jenkins pipeline Git command?

Currently I'm doing this...

```
git branch: 'master',
    credentialsId: 'bitbucket',
    url: 'ssh://bitbucket.org/hello.git'
```

It doesn't however update submodule once cloned

Comment: I find this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54758293/3061838 to a similar question easier than those below.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

With the current [Git plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin), you don't even need that.

> The Git plugin supports repositories with submodules which in turn have submodules themselves.
> This must be turned on though:
>
> in Job Configuration -> Section Source Code Management, Git -> Advanced Button (under Branches to build) -> Recursively update submodules

But the OP is using pipeline.

So a simple first build step is enough:

```
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

However, the OP adds:

> Yes but if I'm using `sh 'git submodule update --init --recursive'`, this will use `$HOME/id_rsa` right? I want to pass in my private key for this command if possible.

It is possible: In the [Pipeline syntax](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/), you can [define environment variables](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/environment/).
Which means you can set `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` ([with Git 2.10+](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38474220/6309)).
That allows you to [reference your own private key](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38474137/6309).

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    environment {
        GIT_SSH_COMMAND = 'ssh -i /path/to/my/private/key'
    }

    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                sh 'printenv'
                sh 'git submodule update --init --recursive'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If any clone involve an ssh url, that ssh clone will use the right private key.

---

Note that [sancelot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1033326/sancelot) points out [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42290133/jenkins-pipeline-git-command-submodule-update/42290216#comment126174180_42290216):

> unfortunately this does not work: [`JENKINS-38860`](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-38860)

> The error reported above:
>
> ```
> FATAL: Command "git config --get submodule.MySubModule.url" 
> returned status code 1
> ```
>
> Occurs for me whenever you have nested submodules.
>
> Consider a scenario in which repo `A` contains submodule `B`, which contains submodule `C`.
>
> If "`Advanced submodule behaviour`" with "`Recursively update submodules`" is *not* enabled, Jenkins will clone `A`, checkout/clone `B`, and fail to initialise/clone `C`.
> This is probably expected behaviour.
>
> If you enable "`Recursively update submodules`", you get the error:
>
> ```
> FATAL: Command "git config --get submodule.C.url"
> returned status code 1
> ```

Comment: This is with git pipeline though. How can I configure with Pipeline project?

Comment: @PassionateDeveloper no pipeline required: the regular Git plugin is enough.

Comment: I'm using Pipeline script and it calls ```git``` command inside it. I don't have option to change Job Configuration -> Section Source Code Management.

Comment: @PassionateDeveloper then a build step in your pipeline script is enough: git submodule update --ini- --recursive as mention"ed

Comment: Yes but if I'm using ```sh 'git submodule update --init --recursive'``` this will use $HOME/id_rsa right? I want to pass in my private key for this command if possible...

Comment: @PassionateDeveloper OK, I have edited my answer to address that specific use case with Jenkins pipeline.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to use credentials id instead?

Comment: @PassionateDeveloper what do you mean "credential id"? Credentials are for https url (username/password). Or do you refer to passphrase protexted private ssh keys?

Comment: yes. Credentials stored as "SSH Username and private key" in Jenkins can be retrieved via credentialsId when doing git clone in pipeline. I'm trying to find a clean way to do `sh 'git submodule update --init'` inside pipeline

Comment: @PassionateDeveloper not that I know of: I see `credentialsId` in https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-26085, so check if your build step used *after* the git clone still uses that. If not, maybe https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/204897020-Fetch-a-userid-and-password-from-a-Credential-object-in-a-Pipeline-job- could help, using https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Credentials+Binding+Plugin

Comment: what about adding id_rsa to ```$HOME/id_rsa``` inside Jenkins slave? I did that but it still errors with `permission denied` when I do ```git submodule update```

Comment: @PassionateDeveloper Then my answer remains the simplest way: make sure the private key is accessible from the agent where the git clone occurs, and GIT_SSH_COMMAND will make it work.

Comment: @PassionateDeveloper again, if you add `id_rsa` anywhere, simply reference it with its full path (not `~/...`, but `/full/complete/path/to/id_rsa`) with `GIT_SSH_COMMAND`, and this will work

Comment: Just tried this and it doesn't work. I'm getting the same error

Comment: Do you have git 2.10 or more on your Jenkins agent?

Comment: It's 2.1.4 so that's why. I just ended up saving private key to home directory of the root user `/root/.ssh/id_rsa` interestingly `$HOME` of the root user was `/home/jenkins` which I was saving that private key to and wasn't working before. So I think it's ok for now.

Comment: OK. But if you can, upgrade to Git 2.11.1.

Comment: @VonC IMPRESSIVE ANSWER - I like the way you handled all the post-question questions. Thank you!

Comment: This works if you have once cloned git already. But with a fresh install, you will not have this luxury... why does git plugin not just offer an "recursive" option? I do not get it

Comment: @IceFire At least Git, in its latest iteration, does: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3797061/6309

Comment: @VonC Of course, Git has that. We talk about the Jenkins plugin here

Comment: @IceFire I mean, Git has that... only since Git 2.23 (August 2019), so... the Jenkins Git plugin has some catching up to do.

Comment: @VonC Ah, for this specific command, you are right. But in the same answer, `git clone --recursive` is also around and this part is from 2010. I would also say that it is best practice to add submodules to Git and that, clearly, no project works if submodules are not checked out. So, it is quite awkward that this basic function is not embedded (or at least allowed for with custom parameters)... anyway, I use ' checkout' now instead of 'git' and this works fine

Comment: I'm currently running Jenkins on a Windows box, and I'm trying to do something similar but also reference stored credentials in Jenkins.  I use the ```withCredentials([sshUserPrivateKey...``` block to access the credentials and inside I use the ```withEnv()``` to set the GIT_SSH_COMMAND before running ```bat script: 'git submodule update --init --recursive'``` but I'm getting a failed login because the credentials aren't being used. Am I missing something?

Comment: @daitienshi Not sure: that would be best as a separate question, with the version of the OS, Git and Jenkins added to it.

Comment: unfortunately this does not work https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-38860

Comment: @sancelot Thank you for this feedback. I have edited the answer to make that issue visible. Do you confirm you are using the latest Git Jenkins plugin version? On which OS do you see the error? Are you using (on that Jenkins controller server) the latest Git 2.35.1.2 version?

Answer (score 62):

The [git command](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/git/#git-git) as a pipeline step is rather limited as it provides a default implementation of the more complex [checkout command](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-scm-step/#checkout-general-scm). For more advanced configuration, you should use [checkout command](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-scm-step/#checkout-general-scm), for which you can pass a whole lot of parameters, including the desired submodules configuration.

What you want to use is probably something like this :

```
checkout([$class: 'GitSCM',
          branches: [[name: '*/master']],
          doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false,
          extensions: [[$class: 'SubmoduleOption',
                        disableSubmodules: false,
                        parentCredentials: false,
                        recursiveSubmodules: true,
                        reference: '',
                        trackingSubmodules: false]], 
          submoduleCfg: [], 
          userRemoteConfigs: [[url: 'your-git-server/your-git-repository']]])
```

From the documentation it is often cumbersome to write these kind of lines, I recommand you use instead Jenkins very good `Snippet Generator` (YourJenkins > yourProject > PipelineSyntax) to automatically generate the checkout line !

Comment: I just ran with above and got `hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git submodule update --init --recursive common" returned status code 1:`

Comment: Don't you have any other output in the console logs ? If you don't, you should maybe try the failed command directly on your Jenkins instance (if you have access) to make sure your submodule "common" can be updated manually

Comment: I've tried it manually on my Jenkins instance and it doesn't work either. Basically same error with `Permission denied (publickey).`

Comment: Okay, so that's a different problem : you don't have permission to clone your submodule repository. The submodule repository should have the same public SSH key configure in Bitbucket so you can checkout it.

Comment: Nice command (+1) But as I mention in my answer, this is more about an ssh configuration issue.

Comment: Yes, but you are giving answers and code examples for declarative pipelines syntax whereas @PassionateDeveloper seems to be using jenkins pipelines standard syntax

Comment: By adding a "checkout" does it replace the default "General SCM" that pipelines does, or is it in addition to?

Comment: For those getting a `Permission denied (publickey)`. You must have the credentials on the same line as the URL, such as: `userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: '45345trete-92eb-4eb0-8844-1fd7ghj76', url: 'ssh://git@bitbucket.....git']]])` . To get the  _Credentials ID_, click on _Credentials_ in the right toolbar of your Jenkins homepage. You will see a table of your credentials and **ID** is a field of that table.

Comment: If you use credentialsId in userRemoteConfigs, you should also use **parentCredentials: true** in subModuleOption, if not permission denied will keep coming :)

Comment: great answer and also nice tip with the "PipelineSyntax tool", thank you!

Comment: Why re-specify the branch here, why not just use scm.branches? Similar for userRemoteConfigs, why not use scm.userRemoteConfigs?

Answer (score 31):

```
checkout([
    $class: 'GitSCM', 
    branches: scm.branches, 
    doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, 
    extensions: [[
      $class: 'SubmoduleOption', 
      disableSubmodules: false, 
      parentCredentials: true, 
      recursiveSubmodules: true, 
      reference: '', 
      trackingSubmodules: false
    ]], 
    submoduleCfg: [], 
    userRemoteConfigs: scm.userRemoteConfigs
  ])
```

Comment: I came back and tried to upvote ... only to notice I'd been here before ‍♂️
Anywho, thanks again.

Comment: I prefer this answer for its use of scm.branches and scm.userRemoteConfigs, which I believe reuses the info entered in the Jenkins GUI, that avoids confusion & repetition.

Answer (score 3):

If you know the credential name that `checkout scm` is using, you can also explicitly pass that to a git command to update the submodules:

```
    stage ('Clone') {
        steps {
            checkout scm
            withCredentials([sshUserPrivateKey(credentialsId: 'bitbucket_ssh', keyFileVariable: 'SSH_KEY')]) {
                sh 'GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -i $SSH_KEY" git submodule update --init'
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a minor variation on the previous answers but I believe it to be the best solution.

I swapped the branches parameter to use `env.GIT_COMMIT` so that it checks out the specific commit that has been triggered via the job.   Otherwise it will build the latest commit of the specific branch, in the other examples, when using `scm.branches`, it will build the tip of the branch instead of the expected commit.

```
checkout([
    $class: 'GitSCM',
    branches: [[name: "${env.GIT_COMMIT}"]],
    doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false,
    extensions: [[
        $class: 'SubmoduleOption',
        disableSubmodules: false,
        parentCredentials: true,
        recursiveSubmodules: true,
        reference: '',
        trackingSubmodules: false
    ]],
    submoduleCfg: [],
    userRemoteConfigs: scm.userRemoteConfigs
    ])
```