# Jenkins Reports Permission Failure When Pulling Submodule via Git Plugin (Remote Repo Bitbucket)

Tags: git, jenkins, bitbucket

I've got a project in Bitbucket (cloud), which I'm building with Jenkins (hosted on-prem). The project has a submodule. If I ignore the submodule, the job (in Jenkins) succeeds. If I attempt to update the submodule, I get this love note:

```
stderr: Cloning into 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Jenkins/workspace/my.repository/lambda/messages'...
git@bitbucket.org: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

The full job log with my SCM configuration is below for reference.

We're using an app-password in Bitbucket to access the repository.

Things I tried...

1. Update Git plugin to v4.1.1 - per [Jenkins pipeline git
   command submodule update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42290133/jenkins-pipeline-git-command-submodule-update/42293620)
2. Created a separate job to pull the submodule's repo using the same credentials. I was able to pull the repo from Jenkins using the same credentials as problematic job without issue.
3. Submodule is in the lambda/messages directory; that's correct

Contents of my project's `.gitmodules` file...

```
[submodule "lambda/messages"]
        path = lambda/messages
        url = git@bitbucket.org:myCompany/myRespository.git
```

Output from the Jenkins job...

```
Started by user myUser
Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Started by user myUser
Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\myRespository
using credential Bitbucket
> git.exe rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
> git.exe config remote.origin.url https://myUser@bitbucket.org/myCompany/deco4-aws.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://myUser@bitbucket.org/myCompany/deco4-aws.git
> git.exe --version # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials Bitbucket App password for Jenkins
> git.exe fetch --tags --progress -- https://myUser@bitbucket.org/myCompany/deco4-aws.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
> git.exe rev-parse "refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit}" # timeout=10
> git.exe rev-parse "refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit}" # timeout=10
Checking out Revision cecc872074937f981a9c593b931440b320b2ea32 (refs/remotes/origin/master)
> git.exe config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
> git.exe checkout -f cecc872074937f981a9c593b931440b320b2ea32 # timeout=10
Commit message: "PS-2315: added thing vars/api/lambda"
> git.exe rev-list --no-walk cecc872074937f981a9c593b931440b320b2ea32 # timeout=10
> git.exe remote # timeout=10
> git.exe submodule init # timeout=10
> git.exe submodule sync # timeout=10
> git.exe config --get remote.origin.url # timeout=10
> git.exe submodule init # timeout=10
> git.exe config -f .gitmodules --get-regexp ^submodule\.(.+)\.url # timeout=10
> git.exe config --get submodule.lambda/messages.url # timeout=10
> git.exe remote # timeout=10
> git.exe config --get remote.origin.url # timeout=10
> git.exe config -f .gitmodules --get submodule.lambda/messages.path # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials Bitbucket App password for Jenkins
> git.exe submodule update --init --recursive lambda/messages # timeout=10
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git.exe submodule update --init --recursive lambda/messages" returned status code 1:
stdout: 
stderr: Cloning into 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Jenkins/workspace/my.repository/lambda/messages'...
git@bitbucket.org: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
fatal: clone of 'git@bitbucket.org:myCompany/deco4-messaging.git' into submodule path 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Jenkins/workspace/my.repository/lambda/messages' failed
Failed to clone 'lambda/messages'. Retry scheduled
Cloning into 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Jenkins/workspace/my.repository/lambda/messages'...
git@bitbucket.org: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
fatal: clone of 'git@bitbucket.org:myCompany/deco4-messaging.git' into submodule path 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Jenkins/workspace/my.repository/lambda/messages' failed
Failed to clone 'lambda/messages' a second time, aborting
using credential Bitbucket
> git.exe rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
> git.exe config remote.origin.url https://myUser@bitbucket.org/myCompany/deco4-aws.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://myUser@bitbucket.org/myCompany/deco4-aws.git
> git.exe --version # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials Bitbucket App password for Jenkins
> git.exe fetch --tags --progress -- https://myUser@bitbucket.org/myCompany/deco4-aws.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
> git.exe rev-parse "refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit}" # timeout=10
> git.exe rev-parse "refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit}" # timeout=10
Checking out Revision cecc872074937f981a9c593b931440b320b2ea32 (refs/remotes/origin/master)
> git.exe config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
> git.exe checkout -f cecc872074937f981a9c593b931440b320b2ea32 # timeout=10
Commit message: "PS-3176: added more things vars/api/lambda"
> git.exe rev-list --no-walk cecc872074937f981a9c593b931440b320b2ea32 # timeout=10
> git.exe remote # timeout=10
> git.exe submodule init # timeout=10
> git.exe submodule sync # timeout=10
> git.exe config --get remote.origin.url # timeout=10
> git.exe submodule init # timeout=10
> git.exe config -f .gitmodules --get-regexp ^submodule\.(.+)\.url # timeout=10
> git.exe config --get submodule.lambda/messages.url # timeout=10
> git.exe remote # timeout=10
> git.exe config --get remote.origin.url # timeout=10
> git.exe config -f .gitmodules --get submodule.lambda/messages.path # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials Bitbucket App password for Jenkins
> git.exe submodule update --init --recursive lambda/messages # timeout=10
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git.exe submodule update --init --recursive lambda/messages" returned status code 1:
stdout: 
stderr: Cloning into 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Jenkins/workspace/my.repository/lambda/messages'...
git@bitbucket.org: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
fatal: clone of 'git@bitbucket.org:myCompany/deco4-messaging.git' into submodule path 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Jenkins/workspace/my.repository/lambda/messages' failed
Failed to clone 'lambda/messages'. Retry scheduled
Cloning into 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Jenkins/workspace/my.repository/lambda/messages'...
git@bitbucket.org: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
fatal: clone of 'git@bitbucket.org:myCompany/deco4-messaging.git' into submodule path 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Jenkins/workspace/my.repository/lambda/messages' failed
Failed to clone 'lambda/messages' a second time, aborting
```

Jenkins job's SCM configuration...

[image: Git Configuration in Job]

Running out of ideas on the root cause. Any guidance appreciated.

Comment: As I'm reading my post back, it occurs to me I'm using https on the parent repo URL and ssh for in the .gitmodules file. I think I found my culprit.

Comment: And, that's what it was. The submodule was being accessed via SSH while the parent HTTPS. Since I didn't have any SSH keys setup, Jenkins could authenticate when cloning the submodule.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sub module was being accessed via SSH while the parent HTTPS.

Sub module...

```
[submodule "lambda/messages"]
        path = lambda/messages
        url = git@bitbucket.org:myCompany/myRespository.git
```

Parent repo...

[image]

Since I didn't have any SSH keys setup, Jenkins could authenticate when cloning the submodule. And, now the error makes sense:

```
stderr: Cloning into 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Jenkins/workspace/my.repository/lambda/messages'...
git@bitbucket.org: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

To fix, I reconfigured the sub module in the repository to access it's remote repo via https. The change was made by editing the `./.gitmodules` file in the root of the repository.

```
[submodule "lambda/messages"]
    path = lambda/messages
    url = https://myUser@bitbucket.org/myCompany/myRepository.git
```

The next build succeeded as desired.

Hope this helps someone!