# The argument "-i" passed to GIT_SSH_COMMAND is being ignored

Tags: git, ssh, public-key-encryption

I want to use other IdentityFile for git. I want to use it dynamically, not via config. I'm doing this:

```
  $ GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -i /home/my_user/.ssh/id_ed25519' git pull origin master
  repository access denied.
  fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

  Please make sure you have the correct access rights
  and the repository exists.
```

**The pub key "id_ed25519.pub" is at my bitbucket.**

And this fails too:

```
  $ git pull origin master
  repository access denied.
  fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

  Please make sure you have the correct access rights
  and the repository exists.
```

And:

```
$ git remote -v
origin  git@bitbucket.org:company123/repo456.git (fetch)
origin  git@bitbucket.org:company123/repo456.git (push)
```

**Adding** **"-v"** to **'ssh -i /home/my_user/.ssh/id_ed25519'** reveals that my RSA key is being used, instead of ED. Why?

Answer (score 21):

I had the same issue with the recent Ubuntu version:

Using -vvv revealed following:

```
debug2: key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa (0x5628e48246d0), agent
debug2: key: /home/ubuntu/code/id_rsa (0x5628e4820af0), explicit
```

Adding `-o IdentitiesOnly=yes` solved it.  It tells SSH to ignore identities from ssh-agent (e.g. added with `ssh-add`) which otherwise take precedence.

Full `git` command:

```
GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -i /home/ubuntu/code/id_rsa -F /dev/null' git pull
```

Comment: I added a sentence briefly describing what `IdentitiesOnly` does.  Feel free to edit/revert in case you don't agree with the change.

Answer (score 11):

Check you commands (is git called directly or through an alias) and configuration:
As I mention in "[Using `GIT_SSH_COMMAND`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38474220/6309)", a git config -l might reveal other configuration that would override the environment variable.

Check the return of `git config core.sshCommand`.

Finally, `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` means Git 2.10+, so if your version of Git is too old, you will need to update it first.

Comment: "git too old" was my problem.

Comment: git --version show up "git version 2.33.0" still got this problem.

Comment: @TruongHieu Would git 2.40 have it too?

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone is having this problem with the slight variation of setting `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` on one line, and then **on a different line** actually running the `git` command, please try one of the following:

1. set `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` on the same line:

```
$ GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -i ${key_location}" git clone [...]
```

or....

2. export `GIT_SSH_COMMAND`

```
$ export GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -i ${key_location}"
$ git clone [...]
```

I was setting `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` right after finding which key to use, and then running `git` a few lines later. I mistakenly removed the `export` and it broke the `git` command.

---

Since this is one of the top google links when searching for "GIT_SSH_COMMAND" and the question is more upvoted than the answers, it might be that some visitors have the same problem as OP but for a different reason than what the other answers recommend. Hopefully this is helpful for someone.