# Different SSH locations for git?

Tags: windows, git, git-bash

I recently reinstalled Windows on my PC.  However the new SSH location on my PC is different because the username is different.  When I try to sync git, it still looks for the previous ssh location.

My question is simply why is it looking for the previous location?

**EDIT**

I forgot to mention that I copied all my repositories and .ssh folder over.

Comment: What do you mean by the SSH location? do you mean your private key?

Comment: The .ssh folder in your user space (C:/Users/[username/.ssh)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git will always look by default for ssh keys in `%USERPROFILE%\.ssh\id_rsa(.pub)`.

Warning, [with Git 2.19+](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53645530/6309), you need to add the -m PEM option to ssh-keygen:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -m PEM -P ""
```

The only way Git would look elsewhere is if you have restored your `%USERPROFILE%\.ssh\config` file, in which you could have set a specific path for a private key.

Comment: You are right.  I copied and stored my entire .ssh folder since I had multiple keys I was using.  In the config file, I had to update the location it was looking for my keys.

Comment: @gagarwa OK, that makes sense: the config can specify through the IdentityFile entry a different path. Note that environment variable can also influence said path, since Git 2.10+: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38474220/6309

Answer (score 0):

all it's looking for is the private key. since you reinstalled Windows, you would have lost you previous key. only option you have is to generate a new key and configure it's corresponding public key on git again.

**P.S: you are incorrect in assuming that it's due to change in location or that git's even looking for your key at a certain location.**