# How to Figure Which SSH Client is Used by Git in Git Bash on Windows

Tags: git, ssh

I want to figure which SSH client is used by git commands when running git bash on windows.
Is there any git command I can run that will display the ssh client path?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a recent enough `git version`, you can use [trace2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56094711/6309) to display what Git is trying to do:

```
GIT_TRACE2=1 git clone git@github.com:<me>/<myrepo>
GIT_TRACE2_EVENT=1 git clone git@github.com:<me>/<myrepo>
```

You can also set the [`GIT_SSH_COMMAND` environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38474220/6309) to `ssh` (including its full path) if you want to make sure which SSH client is used.

---

[Jacob Stamm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4028303/jacob-stamm) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65580457/how-to-figure-which-ssh-client-is-used-by-git-in-git-bash-on-windows/65580709?noredirect=1#comment131071561_65580709), to illustrate that approach:

> I was working in a Docker container from Windows, and from within the container, Git was trying to use `C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe` for SSH and failing.
>
> Setting `ENV GIT_SSH_COMMAND /usr/bin/ssh` in my Dockerfile and rebuilding my container solved the issue. T

Comment: This will show something like `child_start[0] ssh ...` which isn't terribly helpful since its still unclear which `ssh` is run.

Comment: @CervEd "which ssh"? Do you mean you have multiple ssh installed?

Comment: with Git for Windows one might have both the Git for Windows OpenSSH client as well as the Windows OpenSSH client, both as `ssh`. If running `which ssh` returns what is later run by the git process that's great. In my case I had switched back to the Git for Windows `ssh` client, `which ssh` returned `/usr/bin/ssh`

Comment: @CervEd True. I always set the PATH to make sure to use the Git For Windows SSH one.

Comment: I recently installed on a new machine using the new option to use the native client but found myself reverting. Then I got problems with handshakes and I just wanted to make sure which client was being used

Comment: I was working [in a Docker container from Windows](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/devcontainers/containers), and from within the container, git was trying to use `C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe` for SSH and failing. Setting `ENV GIT_SSH_COMMAND /usr/bin/ssh` in my Dockerfile and rebuilding my container solved the issue. Thanks!

Comment: @JacobStamm Thank you for this feedback, well done! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.