# How can I prevent git from asking for the passphrase for a ssh signing key when signing commits or tags?

Tags: git, github, ssh, ssh-agent

When I sign commits or tags with my ssh key (`git commit` or `git tag -s`), git keeps asking for the passphrase of that key. However, I do not want to enter the passphrase for every commit.

I use two different keys for authentication and for signing. Both keys are added to the ssh-agent and I do not have to enter the passphrase for the authentication key. Therefore, the ssh-agent seems to work.

This is my git config:

```
[user]
    signingkey = C:/Users/<username>/.ssh/id_ed25519_github_signing.pub
[core]
    sshCommand = C:/Windows/System32/OpenSSH/ssh.exe
[gpg]
    format = ssh
[commit]
    gpgSign = true
[tag]
    gpgSign = true
```

This is my ssh config, which only contains a config for the authentication key:

```
Host *
    IdentitiesOnly yes

Host github.com
    IdentityFile C:/Users/<username>/.ssh/id_ed25519_github
```

This is the `ssh-add -L` output:

```
ssh-ed25519 <authentication pub key> <username>@mail.com
ssh-ed25519 <signing pub key> <username>@mail.com
```

I already added the key to the ssh-agent and expected that I do not have to enter the passphrase anymore.

I also tried to use the authentication key for signing commits and then I also have to enter the passphrase for that key.

Could it be that git uses "its own" openssh for signing commits instead of window's openssh, even though I configured the ssh command?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10166916/7976758 "*Signing each commit is totally stupid. It just means that you automate it, and you make the signature worth less. It also doesn't add any real value, since the way the git DAG-chain of SHA1's work, you only ever need one signature to make all the commits reachable from that one be effectively covered by that one. So signing each commit is simply missing the point.*" Linus Torvalds. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/212216

Comment: One of the comments: "I feel like Linus is kind of missing the point. He seems to have an entirely different use case for signed commits in mind than the OP in that thread. (Verifying the integrity of the entire project, vs verifying the authorship of a single commit.)" So I with the signature, I want to say that that commit is from me and not from someone else. Why is that a bad thing? It is not that I want to verify the whole project, which would be the case for a signed tag, in my opinion. Can you clarify that?

Comment: Signing commits is not bad. Automating passphrase is bad. Enter passphrase on every signing. When you're tired stop signing every commit, sign tags.

Comment: **1:** Try to see debug output when committing: (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/17344517/923560 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/65580709/923560 ) ... **2:** what is your **git's "provenance"**? Is it git-scm.com's "git-for-windows" or from the cygwin package manager or from a WSL machine or from a VirtualBox machine or ...? Compare that to your **ssh's "provenance"**. Are the provenances identical? Because if they are, they may use different `.gitconfig` configuration sources. ... **3:** what is the value and kind of the `SSH_AUTH_SOCKET` variable when trying to sign? it needs to be exported.

Answer (score 1):

> Could it be that git uses "its own" openssh for signing commits instead of window's openssh, even though I configured the ssh command?

Yes. Use:

```
git config --global gpg.ssh.program "C:\Program Files\OpenSSH\ssh-keygen.exe"
```

with the appropriate path, if you want to be using Windows OpenSSH and SSH agent. Do not forget to check that your SSH agent works otherwise (e.g. with regular SSH connections).

Set `GIT_SSH` environment variable to `C:\Program Files\OpenSSH\ssh.exe` (or the appropriate path), you will need to restart your shell, after you've done that.