# How to check git submodule update status while cloning

Tags: git

I have fired git submodule update --init command and it's showing cloning for last 2 hours. I am not sure if something is broken or something went wrong.
How can I check what's going behind the scene. All I can see is

```
user@user:~/Desktop/src$ git submodule update --init
Submodule 'src/' (ssh://git-master.xxx.com:12001/xxx) registered for path 'src/'
Submodule 'src/dpp/xyz' (ssh://git@gitlab-master.xxx.com:12051/some-app.git) registered for path 'src/dpp/xyz'
Cloning into '/home/user/Desktop/src'...
Total 2862 (delta 4), reused 2853 (delta 4)
Cloning into '/home/user/Desktop/src/dpp/xyz'...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a recent Git, you can export [trace2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56094711/6309) to display what Git is trying to do:

```
GIT_TRACE2=1 git submodule update --init
GIT_TRACE2_EVENT=1 submodule update --init
```

You can also set the [`GIT_SSH_COMMAND` environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38474220/6309) to `ssh` (including its full path) if you want to see how those SSH calls are fairing.