# npm install: avoid GitHub login popup and use SSH private key

Tags: github, npm, ssh

## What I have

- **Private GitHub repository**: a NodeJS private module/package.
- SSH private-public keys created with `ssh-keygen`:

  - **Private key** stored at `C:\Users\USER\.ssh\id_rsa`.
  - **Public key** [added to GitHub](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account).

## What I want

To install the private module (hosted on GitHub) using:

- `npm install`
- SSH public-private authentication (in particular, using the `id_rsa` SSH private key saved in `C:\Users\USER\.ssh`).

## What happen

When I execute:

```
npm install git@github.com:USER/REPO.git --save
```

the following popup is shown:

[image]

I want to avoid this popup. Instead, the `id_rsa` SSH private key password must be request.

If I execute a command using `git` utility like this:

```
git clone git@github.com:USER/REPO.git
```

the SSH private key is used:

```
Cloning into 'REPO'...
Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/USER/.ssh/id_rsa':
remote: Enumerating objects: 20, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (20/20), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (12/12), done.
remote: Total 20 (delta 4), reused 20 (delta 4), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (20/20), done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (4/4), done.
```

## Environment

- Windows 10 Pro 21H1 19043.1526
- NodeJS 16.13.1
- NPM 7.19.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must understand where your git config file lives   https://www.theserverside.com/blog/Coffee-Talk-Java-News-Stories-and-Opinions/Where-system-global-and-local-Windows-Git-config-files-are-saved

after you have identified where your .gitconfig file lives give it values similar to below

```
[user]
    email = myemail@example.com
    name = My Name John Doe
[color]
    ui = true
[push]
    default = simple
[alias]
    co = checkout

[url "ssh://git@github.com/"]
    insteadOf = https://github.com/


[core]
    sshcommand=ssh -i ~/.ssh/my_ssh_key_name

[pull]
    rebase = false
```

then save above gitconfig file ... assure you update above with actual values especially the location of your ssh key file

now engage your ssh key by issing

```
ssh-add ~\.ssh\my_ssh_key_filename
```

for further details see  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_keymanagement

also read this  [Using GIT_SSH_COMMAND in Git for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31475646/using-git-ssh-command-in-git-for-windows)