# How do I track down why I'm getting a github login popup when running npm install on a package

Tags: git, npm

I've started a new project.  I'm using `ssh-agent` and an ssh key for cloning and updating github.  On three different githhub repos, when I run

```
git clone git@github.com:mygithub/example.git
cd example
npm install
```

I get the popup:

[image]

I did a search and found

- [npm install: avoid GitHub login popup and use SSH private key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71194885/npm-install-avoid-github-login-popup-and-use-ssh-private-key)

But I'm already using a pub/private keypair for github.

Four GitHub login dialog windows popped up, but after I click the X in the login dialog, the npm install keeps running and finishes installing everything (I think).

The last line printed in the `npm install` before one of the dialog prompts was:

```
[#####] \ reify:core-js: timing reifyNode:node_modules/es-abstract Completed in 11908ms
```

**What in my package.json is causing the GitHub Signin dialog to popup?**  **How can I track this problem down?  Is there a verbose mode for debug logging to show when this dialog is opened?**

Answer (score 1):

A GitHub login popup is likely coming from a dependencies that is listed in github that is "password" protected (like a private GitHub repo).

The general syntax is `https://example.com/some/package/not-published-in-npm.tgz`.

Below I give commands to illustrate the reason this happens.
In this example, I use a public GitHub repo https://github.com/sindresorhus/is to illustrate the kind of URL that causes the popup (for a private GitHub repo).

The following set of commands allow you to experiment yourself in a safe test directory `test-git-popup`.  The package `@sindresorhus/is` is installed using it's GitHub location.

```
mkdir test-git-popup
cd test-git-popup
npm init -y
npm install https://github.com/sindresorhus/is/tarball/v0.14.0
cat package.json
 . . . truncated . . .
  "dependencies": {
    "@sindresorhus/is": "https://github.com/sindresorhus/is/tarball/v0.14.0"
  }
```

The above should work without a GitHub login popup because the resource is located in a public GitHub repository.

If, however, the GitHub repository were private then a GitHub login popup would occur.  That popup looks like this:

[image]

In Summary: Public GitHub repositories don't require user's to login to access them but private repositories do require a login.

In my case, the npm package being requested was located in a private GitHub repository.

To illustrate the problem using the browser, open the URL listed (in the `package.json` file using an **incognito browser session**.
In my example, the URL would be: https://github.com/sindresorhus/is/tarball/v0.14.0 because of the dependency listed as:

```
    "@sindresorhus/is": "https://github.com/sindresorhus/is/tarball/v0.14.0"
```

If, after opening that URL (from an incognito session), if you see a screen that requires you to login, then this is the equivalent to what is happening when npm is trying to access the resource.
Below is the screen I saw when trying to access a resource from a private GitHub repo.

[image]