# Change windows user config for git bash

Tags: windows, git, bash, ssh

when I open git bash it prompts something like

```
Christoph@DESKTOP-S0OT8DA MINGW64 /c
```

but I'm not christoph and actually my username in computer is renamed to Dani, I want git to show Dani@whatever... currentFolder
because otherwise when I do git clone ssh://..... it tries to log me with christoph user but I'm not

Comment: You might want to consider configuring your ssh, to at least solve your git problem (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26266778/ssh-config-file-for-windows-git#26279306)

Comment: tried but idk what should I configure there, tried steps shown and nothing changed, I didn't even have config file now I do but everything is exactly the same @LinFelix