# Cannot establish ssh connection to Bitbucket repository on Windows

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket

I generated ssh key pair on Windows 10 added private key to `ssh-add` client added public key to Bitbucket.

I run `ssh -T git@bitbucket.org` to check that everything is ok and have next output

```
logged in as myusername
You can use git or hg to connect to Bitbucket. Shell access is disabled
```

I try to clone a repository with ssh `git clone git@bitbucket.org:myusername/test.git` and have authentication issue

```
Cloning into 'test'...
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Any ideas what can be a problem? Only one idea, when generating ssh keypair I saved it to `.ssh` folder but wrote different file name. `ssh-add -l` shows that the key is loaded

```
2048 SHA256:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx C:\......\.ssh\id_bitbucket_rsa (RSA)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a help of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49687394/3457177) I found that if we use custom ssh key pair name we need to add it to the ssh configuration of git.

After I added

```
AddKeysToAgent yes
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_bitbucket_rsa
```

to `c:\Program Files\Git\etc\ssh\` I could clone that repository.