# How to use SSH with alias

Tags: bash, ssh, alias

I have an alias to a server machine:
`alias myserver='user@server'`

however, I cannot ssh into it by using the alias:
`ssh myserver`

`ssh: Could not resolve hostname myserver: Name or service not known`

the alias is correctly set:
`myserver`
returns `bash: user@server: command not found`.

Obviously, it works when I do it extensively:
`ssh user@server`

what is going on? I am pretty sure it has been working until today... But not sure what I changed.
Any help?

Comment: Stackoverflow is for questions about programming, not general command-line usage; the [Unix & Linux stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com) or [Superuser](https://superuser.com) would be better places to ask. But... aliases don't work that way; they function like commands, and cannot be used as arguments (well, except universal aliases in zsh, and in other shells if they follow a command that's also an alias *and* ends in space). But what you really want is an ssh config file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can either have an Alias in your bash configuration which includes the actual `ssh` command aswell ...

`alias myserver='ssh user@myserver'`

... or have an alias in your ssh config file.

```
Host myserver
    HostName 10.10.20.20
    User user
```

`ssh myserver` should work.

A more extensive answer can be found for example [here](https://ostechnix.com/how-to-create-ssh-alias-in-linux/).

Comment: this is so weird. I have been using this solution for months now! It's always been very useful, e.g. I could do `scp ./this myserver:~/that`

Comment: Ok, I realize that I used to have the config file in .ssh with `myserver`, that's why I thought the alias was working! Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about the alias, but I use `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host myserver
HostName server
User user
Port 22
```

Then `ssh myserver` is just like your alias for `ssh user@server`.