# Multiple SSH keys from Windows client to multiple servers

Tags: windows, ubuntu, ssh, ssh-keys, openssh

A lot of people here seem to have the same issue, but with Github.
I don't think that is my issue.

I am fairly new to this so I apologize if this is a duplicate question or if this is a stupid question.

I manage multiple ubuntu servers and I access them from my Windows computer.
I am currently attempting to have ssh keys for all of the servers I have, but it seems like I cannot change the name of the RSA keys or directories. If I do that, the terminal asks me for a password.

### Here's what I did:

#### In my server:

```
mkdir ~/.ssh && chmod 700 ~/.ssh
```

### On my windows machine:

```
ssh-keygen -b 4096
```

#### Prompts me:

Enter file in which to save the key (C:\Users\Me/.ssh/id_rsa):

### Which I enter:

```
C:\Users\Me\.ssh\server1\server1_rsa

scp C:\Users\me\.ssh\server1_rsa.pub server@serverip:~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

(I want to have different directories or something to seperate the SSH keys)

Maybe something like this?

```
/.ssh
  /server1
    server1 pub
    -erver1 priv
  /server2
    server2 pub
    server1 priv
```

or maybe even

```
/.ssh
  server1 pub
  server1 priv
  server2 pub
  server2 priv
```

But this doesnt work.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Please move your question to [su] or [sf] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am sorry if this answer is not making you happy, but I think it will solve your problem :). There is a post on stackoverflow, where you have to add the keys to your ssh-agent.

Kind regards

[.ssh/config file for windows (git)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26266778/ssh-config-file-for-windows-git)

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the fast reply! I've done what the answer said, but I'm not sure what to do next!

Comment: Well you have to name the Identities in the file so that you are able to connect via the named config block element, just look in the answer below its much more accurate than mine :)

Comment: Oh I see! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Solution from [.ssh/config file for windows (git)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26266778/ssh-config-file-for-windows-git)

Create a file called "config" in C:\Users\Me.ssh
(no file extension)

Then add the following information per key/server

```
Host server1ip
User user
Port port
IdentitiesOnly=yes
PreferredAuthentications publickey
PasswordAuthentication no
# CMD
IdentityFile C:\Users\[User]\.ssh\[name_of_PRIVATE_key_file]
# BASH
IdentityFile /c/Users/[User]/.ssh/[name_of_PRIVATE_key_file]
```