# How to force git submodule update to use ipv4?

Tags: git, ipv4

For all other commands there is the `-4` flag that works ([Configure git to use IPv4 instead of IPv6 by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21671706/configure-git-to-use-ipv4-instead-of-ipv6-by-default)), but for `submodule update`, this option does not seem to exist... How to force ipv4 for `git submodule update` ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`foreach`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule#Documentation/git-submodule.txt-foreach--recursiveltcommandgt) to create a custom `git pull`:

> **foreach** [--recursive]
>
> Evaluates an arbitrary shell command in each checked out submodule.

```
git submodule foreach git pull -4
```

Comment: For the first execution, it does not work

Comment: @hl037_ Yes, the problem here is that `git submodule foreach` only looks at the submodules that are initialized. You need a `git submodule init` first.

Comment: even with a git submodule init, it doesn't work