# Gitolite git clone requires ssh password

Tags: git, ssh, github, gitolite

using Gitolite on a Ubuntu server. Have a project im working on that i need a particular syntax for the git command.

Works great:

```
git clone gitolite@servername:testing.git
```

Asks for a password

```
git clone ssh://gitolite@servername/home/gitolite/repositories/testing.git
```

Ran from the same box, one after another. I can put in the password and it works. But I need to automatically work. Sounds like a problem with ssh pub/private keys. Any ideas?

**Update**: Was a problem with file permissions. Not sure the difference between the too commands. But the `/var/log/auth.log` showed some errors

Comment: The commands are running as two different users - the first is using gitolite and the second is as the git user.  If you need the second to work without a password prompt then remove the password protection from the private key file.  If you're using gitolite then you should never use the second option, as you are bypassing gitolite and using SSH directly.

Comment: Also be sure what is asking for a password.  Is your local pub/private key armored and needs a password to decrypt.  'ssh-add' can help unlock the armored local private key, with 'ssh-add -l' to list.  Are you sure it is the server asking for a password and not the local SSH client?

Comment: After ssh-add adding of my identity it is still asking for a password. I created a new pub/priv key when starting. Didn't use a passprhase

Comment: FWIW I run my special SSH server for git on port 19418 with an sshd_config that has "PasswordAuthentication no" and "AllowUsers git" and a number of other lockdowns.  This may not be possible for you using standard SSH port 22 as you may need shell access.  But it helps diagnose problem.

Comment: So you are running a second instance of your ssh server with that configuration?

Comment: Yes exactly.  Copy /etc/sshd/sshd_config and edit.  Copy /etc/init.d/sshd to sshd-git and edit (ensuring to use alternative main config location).  Enable init scripts to start on bootup via /sbin/chkconfig  I am using CentOS server.  You need to add the colon port number syntax in the clone URL for ssh:// URLs, like :19418 that end up in .git/config for [remote "origin"]  url = ....<here>....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to setup ~gitolite/.ssh/authorized_keys with a line like

```
command="/home/gitolite/bin/gl-auth-command <USERNAME>",no-port-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-pty ssh-rsa AAAA...KEY.HERE...ZZZZ== user@label
```

A random URL with info relating to this (see the bottom of the page)

http://www.geekgumbo.com/2011/10/18/ssh-and-the-gitolite-installation-part-2/

Ensure to change ownership of ~gitolite/.ssh/authorized_keys as per SSH requirements with:

```
chown gitolite: ~gitolite/.ssh/authorized_keys
chmod go-w ~gitolite/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

EDIT: to reflect your edits changing 'git' to 'gitolite' system username.

Test your access from the client with:

```
ssh -l gitolite -i <file_id_rsa_foobar> -v -o PasswordAuthentication=no -T <host>
```

Added -T seems needed on my local system to get banner (typed in excuse mistakes):

```
....
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/username/.ssh/id_rsa_foobar
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering DSA public key: /home/username/.ssh/id_dsa_foobar
debug1: Remote: Forced command: /home/gitolite/bin/gl-auth/command <username>
....
hello <username> this is gitolite vX.X.XX-g0123abcd running on git X.X.X
the gitolite config gives you the following access:
    R   W    mydir/project1
....
```

Comment: Right, I have: 
command="/usr/share/gitolite/gl-auth-command dav",no-port-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-pty ssh-rsa KEYKEY username@host

which is why the first command works if Im guessing right

Comment: So when that key is correctly used, the gitolite system will treat the userid as "dav" but you may need to add lines into the file one per user.

Comment: @DarrylMiles `gl-auth-command` is gitolite v2, please upgrade to V3.

Comment: @VonC I'll bear that in mind, v2 is working well for me and no compelling reason to upgrade (have other more useful work to do).  Usage is on private network here.

Comment: Command Ouput(trim)
debug1: Host 'servername' is known and matches the RSA host key.
Permission denied (publickey,password).
debug1: Found key in /h/d/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: id_rsa
debug1: Offering RSA public key: u@h
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.

Comment: Are you 100% sure the "-i <file_id_rsa>" is the SAME key you have installed on the server in authorized_keys file (it is the *.pub part you put on the server) ?  Have you looked in /var/log/messages and /var/log/secure (on server) for any SSH warnings (maybe due to incorrect ownership/file permissions of key files)

Comment: @DarrylMiles It is for sure the same key. Scp'd over just incase it was messed up. Ubuntu auth.log shows:
Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for directory /home/gitolite/.ssh

that dir:
drw-rw-rw- 2 gitolite  gitolite  4.0K Sep 17 23:34 .ssh

Comment: @DarrylMiles Found an issue with that. Changed the permissions so SSHD was happy. It doesn't like group write permissions.
http://recursive-design.com/blog/2010/09/14/ssh-authentication-refused/

Errors gone away, but still requiring a password

Comment: It will not like world write permission either.  'chmod 600 ~gitolite/.ssh' a similar lockdown to in my answer.  drw------- gitolite gitolite (even stricter lockdown as per your URL)

Comment: @DarrylMiles Yup, that did it, it was a permissions thing

Answer (score 0):

If the first version works, that means the public keys have been published under the account named '`gitolite`': `~gitolite/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

The permission issue you have encountered is described here: "[Creating SSH keys for Gerrit and Hudson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3712443/creating-ssh-keys-for-gerrit-and-hudson/3712619#3712619)": note that *all* the parent directories of a .ssh shouldn't have write permission for group or other: `/home`, `/home/yourUser`, `/home/yourUser/.ssh`.

Plus, you shouldn't ever clone a gitolite repo with the full path of the repo: `servername/home/gitolite/repositories/testing.git` is wrong (and would by-pass gitolite completely).
`servername:testing.git` is right.

From the [gitolite V2 doc](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/g2/sts.html#ssh_troubleshooting_common_ssh_problems_):

> The following problem(s) indicate that your pubkey is bypassing gitolite and going straight to a shell
>
> running `git clone git@server:repositories/reponame` (note presence of `repositories/` in URL) works.
>
> [A proper gitolite key will only let you git clone `git@server:reponame` (note absence of `repositories/`)]

Comment: Ok, messed up with the entry, updated. Have been using the right user i setup with.

Comment: @Dishcandanty I noticed, but the address of your second clone doesn't make sense. Why not using the first one only?

Comment: for just simply using the command it makes sense to use the first one. But it is for a plugin on another application with requires the ssh:// path.

Comment: If you have to use `ssh://` why aren't you simply using `ssh://gitolite@servername/testing.git`?

Comment: @AbeVoelker still requires the password with that command. And when i do put the password in it will fail, because it won't find the repository. Otherwise would have to do something like:
git clone ssh://git@192.168.2.205/~/repositories/testing.git

Comment: @Dishcandanty please see my edited answer: using a full pass bypass gitolite.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another thing to try: if AllowGroups is in use for the sshd on the server, check that the git-user is included in one of those groups.