# How to git clone SSH key with passphrase using python?

Tags: python, gitlab, subprocess, pipe

I am new to python and I want to git clone SSH key with passphrase. By referring this https://stackoverflow.com/a/45219868/12095967 , I tried it as:

```py
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

password = 'Password@'
proc = Popen(['git', 'clone', 'git@gitlab.com:gitlab.com/julie/board.git'], stdin=PIPE)
proc.communicate(password)
```

And this is the output it gives:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dell\eclipse-workspace\GitTrial\Git\__init__.py", line 123, in <module>
    proc.communicate(password)
  File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 1009, in communicate
    self._stdin_write(input)
  File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 958, in _stdin_write
    self.stdin.write(input)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
Cloning into 'board'...
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
git@gitlab.com: Permission denied (publickey,password).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I am using windows 10.
Can someone help me out with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logs indicate:

```
...
    proc.communicate(password)
...
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Password should be bytes instead of string:

```py
password = b'Password@'
```

Comment: And abt  Permission denied (publickey,password).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Comment: What happens when you go to console and do it manually? `git clone git@gitlab.com:gitlab.com/julie/board.git`

Comment: Shouldn't this be `git@gitlab.com:julie/board.git`? SSH url to your project seems to be wrong.

Comment: I think it is right as I m able to clone using GitBash , but unable to using python . Can u help me where I can mention the location to where I want to clone ?

Comment: So what is the status does the script work or it still produces `Permission denied` error?

Comment: Can you pipe the password to your gitbash command? I mean something like this `echo Password@ | git clone git@gitlab.com:julie/board.git`

Comment: Is it necessary for you to use ssh with passphrase?