# Using cygwin ssh.exe in TortoiseHg possible?

Tags: mercurial, ssh, cygwin, tortoisehg

I created public and private key with cygwins ssh and pasted the public key into bitbucket account.

```
ssh -T hg@bitbucket.org
```

says the ssh connection works fine! (so it should work!!!)

Then I post

```
[ui]
ssh = C:\cygwin\bin\ssh.exe
```

into mercurial.ini in TortoiseHg

And I post

```
[paths]
default = ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/myusername/personal
```

Into the hgrc file.

But then when I want to push TortoiseHg says to me:

```
remote: Permission denied (publickey).
no suitable response from remote hg
```

Seems to me something is missing here but what exactly?

Edit: I don't want to used TortoisePlink because it is SUPER SUPER SUPER SLOW! And https just cancels the connection after uploading several megabytes.

Comment: Are the permissions correctly set? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3712443/creating-ssh-keys-for-gerrit-and-hudson/3712619#3712619)

Comment: Turn up the logging in the value of `ssh` in `mercurial.ini` and also try adding `--verbose` to your call to `hg push`; the additional logging might help you figure out what the cause of the problem might be.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a password hardcoded into [auth] section of your mercurial.ini?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to specify username and/or port number. 
My mercurial.ini work fine and it looks like this:

```
[ui]
ssh="C:\cygwin64\bin\ssh.exe" -p 22 -l john
```

where john is the username on the remote machine and 22 the ssh port number.