# Git SSH authentication

Tags: git, ssh, public-key-encryption, public-key, atlassian-fisheye

I have Debian, Fisheye and Git on my server.
My git repos are managed by Fisheye. There is no authentication at the Fisheye part. All authentication procedures are managed by git.

I would like to use SSH authentication, so that I do not need to provide username and password as I push my changes to the server. I know how to create an rsa key, but where do I copy my public key at the server?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The key part of the article "[Git on the Server - Setting Up the Server](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server)" is:

> you need to add some developer SSH public keys to the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file for that user.
>   Let’s assume you’ve received a few keys by e-mail and saved them to temporary files. Again, the public keys look something like this:

```
$ cat /tmp/id_rsa.john.pub
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQCB007n/ww+ouN4gSLKssMxXnBOvf9LGt4L
ojG6rs6hPB09j9R/T17/x4lhJA0F3FR1rP6kYBRsWj2aThGw6HXLm9/5zytK6Ztg3RPKK+4k
Yjh6541NYsnEAZuXz0jTTyAUfrtU3Z5E003C4oxOj6H0rfIF1kKI9MAQLMdpGW1GYEIgS9Ez
Sdfd8AcCIicTDWbqLAcU4UpkaX8KyGlLwsNuuGztobF8m72ALC/nLF6JLtPofwFBlgc+myiv
O7TCUSBdLQlgMVOFq1I2uPWQOkOWQAHukEOmfjy2jctxSDBQ220ymjaNsHT4kgtZg2AYYgPq
dAv8JggJICUvax2T9va5 gsg-keypair
```

(Note: make sure the key is displayed on **one** single line)

> You just append them to your authorized_keys file:

```
$ cat /tmp/id_rsa.john.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

If you don't have an `authorized_keys` file on your server, create it, but make sure to protect it correctly.

```
server$ mkdir ~/.ssh
server$ chmod 700 ~/.ssh
server$ cat ~/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
server$ chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
server$ rm ~/id_rsa.pub
```

See "[Creating SSH keys for Gerrit and Hudson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3712619/6309)" for a concrete example.

- Make sure git is in the PATH used by your ssh daemon.
- Make sure all parent directories of your `~/.ssh` are not writable for the group (`chmod 755` only).

Comment: Be aware that this gives you a complete shell/interactive session. Consider using dedicated „git keys“ combined with„forced commands“ to restrict this key to „git only“. *Especially* do this if multiple users use the same „git account“. See e.g. here for an example: https://superuser.com/questions/299927/can-you-specify-git-shell-in-ssh-authorized-keys-to-restrict-access-to-only-git?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: @Jens I agree. That ("ssh forced command") is what I have been using for years with gitolite, that I presented at the time (more than 5 years ago) in https://stackoverflow.com/a/13320256/6309.

Answer (score 1):

You need to paste your public key inside `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`. Create the file if it doesn't exist.