# ssh,github,it doesnot work

Tags: github, ssh

i am sure i upload my ssh key to github, and i also give the folder and file right permition. but i still got this. anyidea?

```
 ➜  python-google  ssh -vT github.com    
    OpenSSH_5.6p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011
    debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
    debug1: Applying options for *
    debug1: Connecting to github.com [0.0.62.138] port 22.
    debug1: Connection established.
    debug1: identity file /Users/seeker/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
    debug1: identity file /Users/seeker/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
    debug1: identity file /Users/seeker/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
    debug1: identity file /Users/seeker/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
    debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.5p1 Debian-6+squeeze1+github8
    debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.5p1 Debian-6+squeeze1+github8 pat OpenSSH*
    debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
    debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.6
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
    debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
    debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
    debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
    debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
    debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
    debug1: Found key in /Users/seeker/.ssh/known_hosts:1
    Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '0.0.62.138' to the list of known hosts.
    debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
    debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
    debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
    debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
    debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
    debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/seeker/.ssh/id_rsa
    debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
    debug1: Trying private key: /Users/seeker/.ssh/id_dsa
    debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
```

i am sure i upload my ssh key to github, and i also give the folder and file right permition.
but i still got this. anyidea?

Answer (score 0):

Check if your ssh public key has been copied as *one* line: It is easy to copy it in multiple lines in the GitHub ssh field.

If is only if your public key is correctly copied and imported on GitHub that `/Users/seeker/.ssh/id_rsa(.pub)` will work (if your ssh directory is [properly protected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13425811/git-ssh-authentication/13428529#13428529)).

---

```
Connecting to github.com [0.0.62.138] port 22.
```

The [GitHub page](https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey) clearly mentions:

```
# debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/you/.ssh/config
# debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
# debug1: Applying options for *
# debug1: Connecting to github.com [207.97.227.239] port 22.
```

> The connection should be to **`207.97.227.239`** on port **`22`**, unless you're overriding settings to use SSH over HTTPS.

Plus make sure you are using /  declaring the `git` user in your config file.
Remove your `~/.ssh/config` file, and try a:

```
 ssh -vT git@github.com
```

Comment: i am sure the key id_rsa.pub in github is right. and permition is ok.

Comment: @user1263778 yet, that looked like http://www.quora.com/Why-is-github-showing-SSH%EF%BC%9APermission-denied-publickey. I have edited my answer with another point to check.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified which user you'd like to authenticate as. When authenticating to GitHub, the user should always be git — not your individual username.

Try `ssh -vT git@github.com` .

Answer (score 0):

Please note that GitHub does not provide shell access.

You need to update your puplic key on github so that you can push. Please follow  [steps](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account/):

you an test your key/ssh connection as mentioned [here](https://help.github.com/articles/testing-your-ssh-connection/)