# Git push "permission denied"

Tags: git, github, push, public-key

I am attempting to push my code to my github account, however whenever I try, i get this

```
Pushing to git@github.com:AlphaModder/Space-Dimension-Mod.git
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Question: how can I avoid that "Permission Denied"? Is the GitHub remote address a valid one?

Comment: See: https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey

Answer (score 6):

I would recommend using the https address for your remote 'origin':

```
https://github.com/AlphaModder/Space-Dimension-Mod.git
```

That would avoid having to deal with all the intricacies of ssh setup.
Plus, you can [cache your credentials too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6191985/git-http-securely-remember-credentials/12938677#12938677).

If you do need an ssh address... then see for instance "[ssh,github,it does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13781035/ssh-github-it-doesnot-work/13781873#13781873)".

Comment: this worked out perfect. I am able to give my credentials after modifying the remote origin to the above-specified format in .git/config ... Thanks