# Moved a gitlab instance, now having problems talking to gitolite

Tags: ssh, gitolite, gitlab

I had a working instance of Gitlab until a few weeks ago, when we had to move all the user directories to another disk b/c of resource constraints.  I've gone through and fixed all the paths that I could find, and so now my gitlab instance is up and running again.  Git appears to be working, and I pass the gitlab self-diagnostic test.

However, from a remote client that's previously worked, I get prompted to provide the git user's password, which suggests an ssh problem.

Looking in my .gitolite stuff (conf/gitolite.conf & the keydir), things look in order. My public key is in the keydir, and the rights are assigned in the gitolite.conf correctly.

EDIT:  gitolite public keys were in the .ssh/authorized_keys file and the protections were as created by gitolite setup.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

> My public key is in the keydir, and the rights are assigned in the gitolite.conf correctly.

This isn't enough.
For ssh to *not* ask you for a password, you need to check if your ~gitlab/.ssh/authorized_keys is complete ([with the gitolite public keys in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13318715/how-do-programs-like-gitolite-work/13320256#13320256), and [with the right protections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13425811/git-ssh-authentication/13428529#13428529))

Check out the [`gitolite setup`](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/setup.html) command (for gitolite V3).

Comment: I apologize, I had checked that already and they are in fact correct as well.

Comment: @Paul then it is time to debug that ssh session: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/922210/unable-to-git-push-master-to-github/922461#922461