# Git unable to push after changeing privileges

Tags: git, ubuntu, gitolite

I have been using a git+gitolite+redmine installation for a long time with no problems. The server is running on ubuntu while I'm developing on windows, and pushing data to the server using a rsa key to log in with.

The only small problem I had, was that redmine repository browser gave me a 404 error. So today I decided to solve that, with 'chmod 777' on my git user home. That worked, but...

Now I can not push to my server from my windows computer (nor pull).

I have changed the access rights on the .ssh directory back to '600'. What else am I missing?

Comment: Please send exact message you are getting from git. Can you ssh to the server - `ssh user@your_server_addr` ? From windows you can use putty to ssh.

Comment: Did you only change the `.ssh` directory or the key files within it too?

Comment: I'm not really getting any error message from git, I'm simple just prompted for at password. It ought to (at least it has till now) just use the rsa key to log in. I have not set a password on the rsa key.

Comment: In /var/log/auth.log I have the folowing entry: Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for directory /var/gitolite

Answer (score 2):

You need, for ssh to work, to make sure no directory is writable for 'group' or 'world' for .ssh and any parent directory.

`.ssh` itself should be in 700, and authorized_keys in `600`: see "[Git SSH authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13425811/git-ssh-authentication/13428529#13428529)".

`777` on homedir will break ssh immediately, as the ssh daemon will refuse to access `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` since part of the path (here the homedir) could be altered by group or others.

Comment: I already have 700 on the .ssh directory and 600 on all the files (id_rsa.pub and authorized_keys) in the directory.

Comment: @user1407209 I am referring to the *parent* directories of `.ssh`, ie `/home/yourUser` (and `/home` itself actually): none of the *parent* directories can be *writable* for 'group' or 'world'.

Comment: Ahh, sorry my mistake. Anyway, the home directory (/var/gitolite) is `755`. Shouldn't that be ok? I have just tried with `644`. Gives me same result.

Comment: Ok, you got me a bit further. Now at least it seems that shh accepts the key. Now I get the error `open log failed: Permission denied`.

Comment: @user1407209 As I mentioned at the end of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13425811/git-ssh-authentication/13428529#13428529, `755` is fine (again check *all* parent directories, from `/` all the way to the homedir)

Comment: @user1407209 looking at https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/master/src/lib/Gitolite/Common.pm#L265-L283, check if you have an environment variable `GL_LOGFILE` or `GL_LOG` (are you using gitolite V2 or v3?), or define it in the `.gitolite.rc` file (https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/master/src/lib/Gitolite/Rc.pm#L94-L103)