# SSH authentication issues (permission denied) with GITHUB

Tags: git, github, ssh

I am running into this permission denied issue.
I know a lot of such posts exists and trust me, I have tried all of them. I have modified the file permissions to 600, I have updated my config file to the following:

```
Host gh
        Hostname github.com
        User git
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
        ForwardAgent yes
```

The log is:

```
    $ ssh -vT git@github.com
OpenSSH_4.6p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8e 23 Feb 2007
debug1: Reading configuration data /c/Users/marker/.ssh/config
debug1: Connecting to github.com [192.30.252.130] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /c/Users/marker/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/marker/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/marker/.ssh/id_dsa type 2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debia
n-5ubuntu1+github5
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1+github5 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_4.6
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /c/Users/marker/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /c/Users/marker/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /c/Users/marker/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/marker/.ssh/identity
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Telnet seems to be working fine and my ssh-agent returns

```
$ ssh-agent
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-FjgkeW2344/agent.2344; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
SSH_AGENT_PID=6020; export SSH_AGENT_PID;
echo Agent pid 6020;
```

I cant seem to understand what the issue is, if anyone can help, that is appreciated!
I use Windows 7 and msysgit.

Comment: Given that the log clearly shows that the private key is loaded, let me ask a question just to be very safe: Did you add the public key of that exact private key to your GitHub account?

Comment: yes, i am pretty sure i did. i ve used the clip command to copy the key. i dont think it can go wrong there...

Comment: It really looks like you didn't add the public key to your git hub account. Go to ~/.ssh and simply open you public key with a text editor and copy it into your github profible.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather specify the full path to your id_rsa private key:

```
IdentityFile /full/path/.ssh/id_rsa
```

If you do have the `id_rsa.pub`, and if every parent directories are [properly protected](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13428529/6309) (not writable for "group"), then double check the key you have copied in your Github profile.

Or try again, with a key *not* protected by a passphrase (meaning not needing an ssh-agent), just to validate that this can work.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can do like this:

```
ssh -vT gh
```

Comment: Could you elaborate more on your answer, so that the OP can learn more about the options you suggest, and how they might help?