# OS X Server + GIT integration with SSH Fails with Permission Denied Error

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, osx-server

I have GIT server hosted on separate Linux server. I have SSH RSA keys **without password**.

I am able to connect to GIT Server with Xcode and all operations are working properly in Source Control through Xcode 5.0.2.

I have OS X Server install in my local machine. 
Following is my OS X Server setup configuration:

1. Added the Remote Repository as : ssh://myuser@XXXXXXX.XXXX.com:22/iphone_project
2. I had make sure that my public is correct in OS X Server for SSH. I had copy paste SSH pub key from /.ssh/id_rsa.pub to OS X Server.

.

```
Cloning into 'ssh_XXXX_XXXX_XXX_com_22_mtp_iphone'...
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to XXXXXX.XXXXXX.com [172.20.10.65] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
Could not create directory '/var/teamsserver/.ssh'.
debug1: identity file /Library/Server/Xcode/Data/BotRuns/BotRun-92b17427-aac4-40fa-92fa-5c73384b7d0f.bundle/credentials/b5964671-8db0-482c-93ee-870a0243295d/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /Library/Server/Xcode/Data/BotRuns/BotRun-92b17427-aac4-40fa-92fa-5c73384b7d0f.bundle/credentials/b5964671-8db0-482c-93ee-870a0243295d/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH_5*
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 26:70:37:3a:56:bd:17:bd:9d:6a:14:c0:21:23:65:1c
debug1: Host 'XXXXXX.XXXX.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Library/Server/Xcode/Config/ssh_known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
debug1: No valid Key exchange context
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1:  Miscellaneous failure (see text)
No credentials cache file found

debug1:  An invalid name was supplied
unknown mech-code 0 for mech 1 2 752 43 14 2

debug1:  Miscellaneous failure (see text)
unknown mech-code 0 for mech 1 3 6 1 5 5 14

debug1:  Miscellaneous failure (see text)
unknown mech-code 2 for mech 1 3 6 1 4 1 311 2 2 10

debug1:  An unsupported mechanism was requested
unknown mech-code 0 for mech 1 3 5 1 5 2 7

debug1:  Miscellaneous failure (see text)
unknown mech-code 0 for mech 1 3 6 1 5 2 5

debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Library/Server/Xcode/Data/BotRuns/BotRun-92b17427-aac4-40fa-92fa-5c73384b7d0f.bundle/credentials/b5964671-8db0-482c-93ee-870a0243295d/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: Device not configured
debug1: permanently_drop_suid: 94
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
Permission denied, please try again.
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: Device not configured
debug1: permanently_drop_suid: 94
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
Permission denied, please try again.
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: Device not configured
debug1: permanently_drop_suid: 94
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.



SSH Known Hosts file path is located at /Library/Server/Xcode/Config/ssh_known_hosts
SSH strict host checking is disabled (you can enable this by editing the SSHStrictHostKeyChecking key in /Library/Server/Xcode/Config/xcsbuildd.plist
Untrusted HTTPS certificates is disabled (you can enable this by editing the TrustSelfSignedSSLCertificates key in /Library/Server/Xcode/Config/xcsbuildd.plist
```

My Question is: Why my authentication is still failing after all configuration setup?

Are there any missing point in set up of GIT or OS X SERVER?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure of the exact account which make the ssh command:

Its `$HOME/.ssh` must have `id_rsa.pub`, *and* `id_rsa` (public *and* private key).

Make sure the permission of the `.ssh` folder and its files is correct, as described in "[Git SSH authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13428529/6309)" .
With EGit, those folder are referenced and declared in "[Eclipse SSH Configuration](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Eclipse_SSH_Configuration)":

[image]

Comment: This is correct but I have set up this things using Eclipse. I dont know how to do without eclipse... but anyways.. my issues got solved... :)

Comment: @DShah Ok. I have added a link to EGit.