# Issue in Bot integration with bitbucket

Tags: git, ssh, xcode5, bitbucket, bots

I am integrating bot using ssh with bitbucket.
I have done all the steps as described in documentation, generate ssh copied it onto bitbucket.
But I keep getting following error always while integrating bot:

```
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server,
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I tried this :

```
ssh -T git@bitbucket.org
```

on terminal and got following output:

```
logged in as my UserName.

You can use git or hg to connect to Bitbucket. Shell access is disabled.
```

How would you troubleshoot that issue?

Comment: Seems similar to another recent, and unanswered question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20674602/os-x-server-git-integration-with-ssh-fails-with-permission-denied-error

Comment: I have updated .ssh folder permission to-
$ chmod 700 ~/.ssh $ chmod 600 ~/.ssh/*

But still getting roaming not allowed by server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is generally because your bot doesn't use the same account than the one your are testig your ssh command.

Make sure the bot has, under its `~/.ssh`, a `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub` (with the latter copied on your BitBucket account, which should be the case since your `ssh -T git@bitbucket.org` works on the terminal).
Check also the permission of that `.ssh` folder and its files (again with the right account used by the bot), as described in "`[Git SSH authentication][1]`" .

---

The [OP rtk123](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2304304/rtk123) confirm [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20825663/issue-in-bot-integration-with-bitbucket/20836333#comment31406251_20836333):

> I was using wrong ssh key with bot on mac osx server: I didn't add ssh key to server repository.

Comment: Thanks VonC, I was using wrong ssh key with bot on mac osx server.