# BitBucket-Git push not completing

Tags: git, bitbucket

Can some help me to sort out an issue regarding pushing the changes in bitbucket repository.

What i have did :

--> I have forked a repository and cloned it with https.

--> Made changes and committed them.

--> But, when i am going to push those changes only the cursor blinks and no changes will be pushed, even the cursor blinked more then 2 hours but nothing happened and i have cancelled the progress.

--> Can you please tell me what i am doing wrong here?

My client told me to setup ssh, i have setup ssh as per instructions of bitbucket.

Please help me to sort out this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you have cloned it with https, that means:

- `git remote -v` should list the remote 'origin' with an https url (and https certificate for BitBuckethas an certificate authority issue right now, being from  [COMODO CA Limited](http://www.instantssl.com/ssl-certificate-products/why_comodo_ssl.html), which isn't always in the certificate keystore of your browser)
- your **[ssh setup](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Set+up+SSH+for+Git)** won't be used unless you change the origin with an ssh url (see "[Use the SSH protocol with Bitbucket](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Use+the+SSH+protocol+with+Bitbucket)")

That means:

```
git remote set-url origin git@bitbucket.org:accountname/reponame.git
```

Then you can try a:

```
git push -u origin master
```

That is, for your first push only, in order to establish a tracking relationship between your local `master` and `origin/master`.
After that, a simple `git push` will be enough for the next commits.

Comment: thank you for your reply. i have changed the remote to ssh.

But now when i am pushing it is showing me you have no proper access rights and Permission Denied (Public Key).

Comment: @JitendraKhatri you need to check your HOME environment variable, and see if  $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa and id_rsa.pub are there, with the right protection (http://stackoverflow.com/a/13428529/6309), and if your public ssh key has been published.