# git push is not using the correct git configuration values

Tags: git

I have in my ~/gitconfig  and in my (repo)/.git/config:

```
[user]
    name=sboesch
    email = stephen.boesch@mycompany.com
```

Are they working? Seems so ..

```
$ git config user.email
stephen.boesch@mycompany.com
[cloudera@localhost hwspark]$ git config user.name
sboesch
```

But when doing a push my old credentials (specifically username=javadba) are being used instead:

```
[cloudera@localhost hwspark]$ git push
remote: Permission to Mycompany-Spark/spark.git denied to javadba.
```

What configuration step am I missing here?

**UPDATE*  more info - from

```
git config -e
```

Output:

```
[remote "origin"]
        url = https://github.com/<companyRepoName>/spark.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/master
[branch "ctx"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/ctx
[user]
        email = stephen.boesch@mycompany.com
        name = sboesch
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main (global) git config file sets your user name and email for new commits you add (to any repository), but (at least normally) does not affect anything else.

Your per-repository git config file contains more-specific instructions, like "the URL(s) to use for fetch and push operations to a named remote".  The usual default remote is named `origin`:

```
$ git config --get remote.origin.url
git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/git/git.git
```

or you can just run `git config -e` to open up the per-repository config file in your configured editor; you should see something like this (this is for my copy of the git source):

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/git/git.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

The `url` sets both fetch and push URLs, unless there's a `pushurl` which sets the push URL.

If the push URL is, e.g., `ssh://user@host/path/to/repo.git`, then git will invoke `ssh` using `user` as the user name.  The ssh transport has its own, entirely-separate, methods of doing authentication: git just invokes ssh and lets ssh take care of everything.

For more about that, see, e.g., [VonC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13428529/1256452) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13425811/1256452).

If the push URL uses some other transport, you'll need authentication based on that other transport.

[**Edit**] You're using https authentication.  See [Git push requires username and password](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6565357/1256452): the simplest fix is to switch to ssh authentication, but if you want to keep using https authentication, check out the other answers.  (The details depend on your own host OS.)

Comment: Hi,  i have updated the OP to reflect that the settings are/were both in the global ~/.gitconfig  and in the repo-local  .git/config

Comment: You can *override* global settings in the local config, but again the `user.name` and `user.email` are *not* the interesting items here, it's the `pushurl` if set, or the `url` if not, that is the next key item.

Comment: It is still unclear to me specifically where the issue is. In any case I have updated the OP to show the git config -e

Comment: OK, this indicates that you're using https authentication.  See edit.

Comment: My original question mentions that the git auth error is showing the wrong username (javadba instead of stephenb).  I still do not see an explanation of that particular error mode in your answer here.

Comment: It still depends on whether you're on OSX or Linux (as far as I know; I haven't used https authentication on either one).  If you're on Linux it may be reading this from `~/.netrc`.  But the main thing here is, you've gone past my knowledge of mixing git with https.  (I use ssh.)  I can't tell you for sure where it *is* coming from, but it's definitely not coming out of any of the standard git config files.

Comment: OK, well I have upvoted anyways since you have added some useful info. Will await more answers for actual award.

Comment: Not really a fully answered question, but i'm awarding since it's all that we got here.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add your username in your config remote "origin" URL (I'd recommend using SSH instead of HTTPS).

Run `git config -e` to open your repository config file.

Add your username like below example:

```
[remote "origin"]
        url = git@github.com-<your-username>:<company-repo-name>/spark.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```