# Can't git clone openshift repository on Ubuntu machine

Tags: git, openshift

I am unable to git clone my application created on openshift free hosting gears on my local machine. I have set up the 'rhc' tools on my machine using the following link

https://developers.openshift.com/managing-your-applications/client-tools.html

It's strange that the public key is updated on the server and I can see a private key on my machine. However when I try to do git clone it gives the below mentioned error.

```
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your OS, make sure HOME is correctly defined (it is not by default on Windows)

`rhc` and `git` look after the public/private `id_rsa(.pub)` keys in `%HOME%\.ssh`

The [OP sanketr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3079531/sanketr) confirms it is a ssh key issue, used on Ubuntu with sudo (I comment that changes `$HOME` to `/root`):

> It was not working for me earlier as the keys were not copied correctly inside the root/`.ssh` folder.

Comment: How do i check it in Ubuntu?

Comment: @SanketR Check the content of $HOME/.ssh, and its chmod (600 for the files, not writable for the folder)

Comment: I checked it and it has id_rsa and id_rsa.pub files inside it. I have also set the permissions to 600 for the .ssh folder, but still the error persists

Comment: @SanketR 600 are for files: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/13428529/6309

Comment: It still persists. I am not sure if the problem is because I have installed rhc tools using sudo. Does it cause permission issues?

Comment: Sudo is not a problem here

Comment: @devprashant Not sure because in windows i use git bash and while writing rhc commands i can run them without using sudo and they work fine, however in Linux they give me error.

Comment: @san but if you are using sudo, home changes to /root. Do you have the ssh keys in /root/.ssh?

Comment: @devprashant I don't have. Willl give a try by creating them at root.

Comment: @devprashant It didn't help even after creating the keys at root. I just copy pasted the .ssh dir

Comment: @devprashant Got it solved as per the suggestion provided by you. It was not working for me earlier as the keys were not copied correctly inside the root/.ssh folder. Thanks a lot mate... :)

Comment: @SanketR Great! I have included the proper resolution in the answer for more visibility (since I was the one suggesting to copy the keys in /root/.ssh).

Comment: @vonc the credit is yours. SanketR mistakenly quoted me in comments. This comment is for clearification for proper thanks giving.

Comment: @devprashant Thank you. No problem, let's wait for the OP's feedback.

Comment: @VonC Apologies. I mistakenly quoted devPrashant's name in my comments without noticing your name. Ofcourse the credit is yours VonC for showing me the light in dark... :)