# Host key verification failed for git from docker

Tags: git, unix, docker

I have a docker container whose job it is to push a file to a git repository.

It refuses to connect to the git repository with the error.

```
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I have tried adding my known_hosts file (which pushes and pulls from the git repo just fine) to the docker using

```
RUN mkdir ~/.ssh
ADD known_hosts ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

But still get the same error. ssh-keygen returns no output, and

```
'GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -o \'UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null\' -i ./ssh_id" git push origin master'
```

didn't fix it either. How can I disable host key verification so that I stop seeing this error?

Comment: I imagine the issue is the lack of private key + ensuring target server has corresponding public key.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Adding `known_hosts` is not enough.

You would need to add as well `~/.ssh/id_rsa` to your docker image in order for an ssh connection to have a chance to succeed.
And you need to make sure everything is in `600` mode (or ssh would refuse to consider that private key): see "[Git SSH authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13428529/6309)".

Try a `RUN ssh -Tv git@github.com` just for testing: that will show you if the `known_host` or the key are the problem here.