# Permission denied (publickey) when cloning in webroot directory but not in ~/.ssh

Tags: git, ubuntu, github, ssh

Running Ubuntu, in case that's relevant.

I already have a Github account, with my public key added, and I'm making a move from Windows to Ubuntu. I went through all the necessary steps to get my credentials setup, then (wisely) cloned a repo of mine into the .ssh directory. Everything worked fine, but...that's not where I want it to be, of course. So I removed the directory I cloned into, actually tried it from the directory where I wanted it to be, and I get:

```
rich@ubuntu:/opt/lampp/htdocs$ sudo git clone git@github.com:Polisurgist/introRecorder.git
Cloning into 'introRecorder'...
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

So for some reason it's able to use my key, but only when I'm cloning into the directory that contains my key. I'm sure I'm missing a step that tells git where to find the key, but I don't know what that step is.

Comment: What happens when you run the same command without sudo?

Comment: Can't create directory...though it does know what directory it's trying to create, so I guess that does fix the ssh problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible it worked the first time because ssh went looking for the public/private keys in the current folder.

But once you moved directories, ssh will look for those same keys in `~/.ssh/id_rsa(.pub)`.
So you need to make sure those keys are there, in the right place (should be `/home/rich/.ssh`), with the right protection (see "[git push failing in gitlab](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3712619/6309)").

Doing the git clone with a sudo will mean ssh would look for those keys in the `root` homedir, which isn't necessarily what you want.

> `/opt/lampp/htdocs`: Can't create directory.

That means you need those keys in `/root/.ssh`, if you want the `git clone` to be done as `root` (see "[Home folder in `root` and not in `home`… I'm confused!](https://askubuntu.com/a/196234/5470)").
But you rather should create that folder as root and change its ownership, and then do the `git clone` as `rich`.

Comment: Yeah, that appears to be the problem. Of course, root is locked on Ubuntu, so I think I can't do that but I can just change permissions in my webroot.