# Git - ssh-key on server

Tags: git, ssh, server, key, local

I created a ssh-key on my local computer and added the public key to my git-account.

Works like a charm.

I am not asked to type my username+password when I clone any repository.

Next, I ssh into my server and created a ssh-key the same way and added the public key to git-account as well.

I did this because I just want to clone/pull from my repository so I have the most stable version from my git-repo on my server.

But when I clone the repository to get it on my server, I am asked for username+password.

What did i wrong or do have to do other stuff?

Comment: What was the root cause in your case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be because:

- either the `git clone ssh://` does not find `id_rsa`/`id_rsa.pub` in `$HOME/.ssh`: check you user account, and [check if the rights on the `$HOME` and `$HOME/.ssh` and the key files themselves are correct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3712619/6309).
- or the public key (`id_rsa.pub`) has been incorrectly copied to your server git account profile (for instance, with a newline in it)