# Jenkins cannot SSH into github

Tags: linux, git, jenkins, ssh

Running ubuntu on EC2 instance. I want to setup Jenkins SSH with my github server, but when I run the command

```
ssh -vT git@github.com
```

I receive the following output:

```
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to github.com [192.30.253.113] port 22.
ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Connection timed out
```

My ssh key for jenkins is located in the /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh folder, but it looks as if ssh config data is being read in the /etc/ folder

I have added the public SSH key to my github account and have verified that I did so as one line.

What else am I missing?

I came across this [Creating SSH keys for Gerrit and Hudson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3712443/creating-ssh-keys-for-gerrit-and-hudson/3712619#3712619) as a potential reason why it is not connecting, but I find it highly unlikely that the last time this occurred for somebody was 5 years ago.

Comment: can you directly ssh to github from jenkin user? ssh jenkins@ like that..

Comment: Will give it a try this afternoon

Answer (score 1):

This looks more like a **networking issue** as you receive a `Connection timed out` error.

So, **first check that you can really connect to the github server**, e.g. using `nmap` or `telnet`; the output should look like this if networking is ok:

```
$ telnet github.com 22
Trying 192.30.253.112...
Connected to github.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
SSH-2.0-libssh-0.7.0
```

`ssh` keys are usually located in `$HOME/.ssh/` (where `$HOME` is the home directory of the user that runs the Jenkins master) -- the folder `/var/lib/jenkins/.ssh` looks at least unusal.

The directory `/etc/ssh` contains system-wide `ssh` configuration data, it will always be read and is not intended for user-specific configuration items.

Comment: the /var/lib/jenkins path is what the user jenkins has access to. I will try using nmap or telnet to see if networking is the issue. okay so I rule out that the directory config isn't the problem

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that EC2 doesn't seem to let me connect to github via port 22.
I tested this via Alex O's suggestion that I attempt to telnet into git

My solution:

1. Use SSH through the HTTPS port
2. Change the config file for github to
       ssh through 443
3. Profit

Major cred to @AlexO